# Postgresql SQL script runs in shell script from terminal but not from cron

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, cron

I am using the below script "load.sh" to run a sql script in postgresql:

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk -i inplace '!a[$0]++' *.txt
mv *.txt txtdir/
sudo -u postgres psql -d datdb -f /var/lib/postgresql/run.sql
exit
```

If I run it as just ./load.sh from the command line as root it works perfectly.

The .sql truncates some tables and loads some data. No issues.

However, if I run it as a cron job, the .sql script does not work.

Nothing changes, but for the fact it is scheduled from cron.

If I pipe the shell script to a logfile using:

```
crontab -l

0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /txtdir/load.sh > /txtdir/load.log
```

The shell script runs I can see, and works and the log does not contain any errors but the sql parts are simply absent from the log and I can see the tables are not being loaded, it is not working from cron.

If I run it all as below though from a terminal session:

```
/txtdir/load.sh > /txtdir/load.log
```

Everything is perfect, I can see the data load references in the log, data is loaded to the tables.

I cannot understand why this would work from the terminal but not from cron whilst both being run by the same user.

Comment: My guess is that psql is not in the path.  Try using the full path to psql in the script.

Comment: Cron sends its standard error as e-mail. Look there!

Comment: Thanks guys... mail isn't actually installed, also, it's not "Failing" as such so I do not think probably i would find an error... I have given the full path to /usr/bin/psql and re-ran in cron, it still misses the sql when it runs with no errors produced and it still runs the sql when the script is run manually

Comment: Cron jobs run with a very limited set of environment variables compared to a login session, so that's the most likely reason for failure.

Comment: What does the Postgres log show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron's default PATH on Linux and macOS is `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. For Linux, psql is usually installed in `/usr/bin`, so it shouldn't be the issue.

The other issue is `sudo`, it will have a number of issues running under cron. First, it will attempt to set up a pty. So on Ubuntu 22 use this:

```
 sudo -b -n -H -u postgres
```

Second, you must modify your `/etc/sudoers` file by running `sudo visudo` and adding a line like this at the bottom:

```
%sudo   ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/psql
```

This allows anyone with sudo permission to run `/usr/bin/psql` to postgres on any host (ALL) with no password.

I add this line for psql to your `load.sh`:

```
cd /txtdir; sudo -b -n -H -u postgres psql -d datdb -f run.sql
```

Add this line to your personal crontab (not-root)

```
* * * * * /txtdir/load.sh > /txtdir/load.log 2>&1
```

The 2>&1 changes where stderr is delivered, in this case to the same output as stdout.